# Как реализовать сетку, похожую на то что в фотошопе

Tags: алгоритм

Что такое сетка вообще и как она работает? Это массив квадратов с координатами, при попадании в которые, объект притягивается к координатам?

Comment: остаток от деления окей, а от чего его брать?

Comment: От координаты курсора

Comment: ну а насчет построения сетки я прав, то что это массив квадратов с координатами?

Comment: Нет, это избыточно. При помощи деления (без остатка) координаты на шаг сетки можно вычислить, к какой из линий сетки ближе расположен курсор, дальше его можно "прилепить" к этой линии

Comment: понял буду писать, что-то вроде как понятно. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При движении курсора вычисляем расстояние между точкой пересечения линий сетки Ps и координатой курсора Pc. Ks - шаг сетки, Sens - диаметр "чувствительности" сетки

```
Ps.x := Round(Pc.x / Ks) * Ks;
Ps.y := Round(Pc.y / Ks) * Ks;
```

я делал функцию

```
class function TMPunkt.Nearby(punktA, punktB: TPoint; sensitivity: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Sqrt(Sqr(punktA.x - punktB.x) + Sqr(punktA.y - punktB.y)) < sensitivity div 2;
end;
```

вызываешь её с данными параметрами

```
 if TMPunkt.Nearby(Pс, Ps, Sens) then begin
   //приравниваем координаты перетаскиваемой точки к сетке
   Pc = Ps;
   //и перерисовываем
 end;
```

В результате, если курсором перетаскиваешь какую либо точку и она попадает в круг вокруг любой из точек пересечения сетки, она к ней "прилипает"

Comment: Получается, что точка может притянуться к левому нижнему углу ячейки, а к остальным - не может, даже если она близко. А вот `Ps.x = (Pc.x + Ks div 2) div Ks;` даcт именно ближайшую опорную точку (подобно вещественному делению с округлением)

Comment: левый нижний край ячейки справа это правый нижний край данной, ячейки сверху это верхний левый и т.д... на то она и сетка, потому хватит одной проверки

Comment: https://ibb.co/R7MLLS6 точка E притянется к A, а хорошо бы к C

Comment: да, я понял что вы имеете ввиду, но работает и так вроде правильно https://cloud.mail.ru/public/YpeR/Du66VJPTc 
но я брал Ps.x := Round(Pc.x / Ks) * Ks; точно... поправил, спасибо